# How to inform remote users a cached data is out of date?

Tags: algorithm, web-services, caching

Our company has built some new webservices. The services provide some large data so it is best to save the data in cache for performance issues. What if new or update data will provide in our webservices, how can we inform our users? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Mailing list? Twitter feed?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to include the expiration / valid till date along with the data response.

Second thing to do is to make a separate web-service method to check if the data has been modified after the given date.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have trade-off between caching, and making sure data is valid - and storing the entire data on your webservice. Finding the right solution is an engineering issue that really depends on your specific case, but here are some pointers and possible approaches:

1. Each entry in the cache must have expiry data, that will be wiped after the time has passed, it will make sure you don't store old data, and your cache is not full of unneccessary information.
2. You can send a message to all your users once some entry is invalidated, that they should take this data out of their cache. This requires your clients to listen to you, and becomes inefficient if data changes often.
3. You can store a hash value of each element, and before using the actual value - check the hash data is correct. This usually requires much less data transfer than checking the actual value, but you can have *false negative* - you think a value is not changed, while in fact it was.
4. In some cases (especially peer-to-peer, but not exclusively) it is wise to use [Merkele Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree). The idea if Merkele trees is that each leaf holds data, and its hash value, and each internal node is a hash of its two sons.

   The idea is you can find out very quickly if no change was made to the cache by checking the value of the root, and finding what was changed is done in `O(logN)`.

   The downside is this DS is probabilistic, and there is a small yet possible chance that a value was changed and you won't detect it. 

   This approach is an efficient generalization of (3)

Ultimately, there is no silver bullet, and the chosen method should fit your specific case, and depends on a lot of factors, some are:

- Size of entry in cache
- Rate of changes of cache
- Web server availability
- Availability to maintain connection with clients
- Is a probabalistic approach enough?
- etc.